# Make an inline-block div take 100% of the remaining width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 `div` blocks inside another `div`.

What I wanted to do is to put them inline, but the first 2 `div` blocks should take a width according to their content and the last `div` take the remaining space.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="green">Green</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
</div>
```

I try to avoid the use of fixed widths because I need to use this in a responsive design.

How can I make the blue `div` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kLVn/) take the rest available space of its parent and act responsive if the screen is resized?

Comment: Are you opposed to using javascript?

Comment: Did you try using percentages?

Comment: set everything to `display: block` and float the first two divs to the left.  the remaining non-floating div will take up the rest of the space.

Comment: @Jack If is possible, i preffer only css :)

Comment: Looks like @Elise answered your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe if you don't want to specify any pixel or percentage widths at all and make the red and green containers only as wide as their content, you will need to wrap them inside their own container, named `.left` below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="red">Red</div>
        <div class="green">green</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

If you now float `.left` to the left, and also float `.left div` to the left, you now no longer need to specify any inline-block elements. The blue container will simply take up as much space as it has available until the end of the `.container`.

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.left div {
    float: left;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8qeZ/2/)**

**Edit**

Silly me, the `.left` container is obviously not needed as long as you just add `float: left` to your red and green blocks, just like @Ennui said above in the comments :)

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8qeZ/3/)**

Comment: This solution has one flaw - background is not floated, so if you give the "filler" element background it will also be under floated element :) There is a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20180165/1835470 ...............
 (`overflow: hidden;`)

Comment: @jave.web Very well pointed, but the overflow:hidden doesn't fix things apparently. Does anyone know the solution? http://jsfiddle.net/48nk23e0/ <- As you can see the yellow background extends under the first element, can that be avoided?

Comment: @NertanLucian it's 2021 now, just use flex :-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox
BTW: in your jsfiddle - a) you added extra border and you have a background in first - bad example b) the overflow goes for the **filler** element as I've described, not for the container => I've altered your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mLc63ayd/

Answer (score 12):

`float: left` the red and green and the blue get `width: calc(100% - 100px)`

```
.blue {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kLVn/190/

Answer (score 2):

Change your css to this:

```css
.container{border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; position: relative; width: 100%;}

.container div {height: 20px;}

.red{border: 2px solid red; display: block; float: left;}

.green{border: 2px solid green; display: block; float: left;}

.blue{border: 2px solid blue;}
```

Tested in Chrome

**EDIT**

Silly me, this is the forked jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BWRVk/

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be responsive, give the `divs` % `widths`.

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/6kLVn/6/

```css
.container div {height: 20px;}

.red{border: 2px solid red;width:10%;display:inline;}

.green{border: 2px solid green;width:10%; display: inline;}

.blue{border: 2px solid blue;display:inline-block;width:80%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is all based on what you want your images to be. I just used % on the images to show they can be resized according to responsive design. http://jsfiddle.net/6kLVn/7/

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container{border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; position: relative; margin:0px; width: 100%;}

.container div {height: 20px; display: inline-block; padding:0px; margin:0px;}

.red{border: 2px solid red; width:31%; }

.green{border: 2px solid green;width:31%;}

.blue{border: 2px solid blue;width:31%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the container `display: flex` , each `div` `flex: 1` and the last `div` give it `flex-shrink: 1; width: 100%`

Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/wtsn3uzh/