# Div background-color does not extend to child divs

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with several child divs within this. The parent div has a background-color, however, this doesn't seem to be extending to the last couple of child divs. Please see code below:

http://codepen.io/tombarton/pen/aNaGGa

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="checkout">
        <div class="left">
                          ...
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="button">
                                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  padding: 0 3%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: justify;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.checkout {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.left {
  display: block;
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that final two divs do not have content, but I'm not 100% sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to clear the floats. Try `overflow:hidden` on the container

Comment: the main reason for this is because `.container{display:block}` and `.checkout{float:right}`. U can use `.container{display:table}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the last floating element within the parent div.

Your new codes becomes this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  padding: 0 3%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: justify;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.inline-row {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 56px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.image-container {
  width: 24%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.product {
  width: 58%;

  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
  }
}

.cost {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: right;
  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
  }
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  width: 3%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

hr {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.checkout {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.left {
  display: block;
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="inline-row image-container">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/56">
      </div>
      <article class="inline-row product">
        <h2>barolo.</h2>
        <p>barolo di castiglione falletto</p>
      </article>
      <div class="inline-row cost"><p>39.99 EUR</p></div>
      <div class="inline-row delete">X</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="inline-row image-container">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/56">
      </div>
      <article class="inline-row product">
        <h2>barolo.</h2>
        <p>barolo di castiglione falletto</p>
      </article>
      <div class="inline-row cost"><p>39.99 EUR</p></div>
      <div class="inline-row delete">X</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="inline-row image-container">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/56">
      </div>
      <article class="inline-row product">
        <h2>barolo.</h2>
        <p>barolo di castiglione falletto</p>
      </article>
      <div class="inline-row cost"><p>39.99 EUR</p></div>
      <div class="inline-row delete">X</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <hr>   
  
  <div class="checkout">
    <div class="left">TOTAL 148.98 EUR</div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="right button">CHECKOUT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/22L7engy/

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Can anyone explain why the float causes this behavior?

Comment: float collapses the parent div height, so we need to either clear it or give "overflow: hidden"

Comment: i use clear: both method, never practically used overflow one, so dnt knw if thts better or what

Answer (score 2):

to apply parent div styles to child div either remove

```
> float:left
```

from child or add float:left to the parent div. hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  padding: 0 3%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: justify;

  overflow: auto;
}
```

Your checkout is floating, so it doesn't apply correctly to how the container behaves

Answer (score 0):

Either in your CSS, or inline, white the code as:

```
#adiv {
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

#anotherdiv {
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

In HTML, make sure you call each div to their respective CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add overflow:hidden or overflow:auto on the container

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20180165/2482513